# Python - Ascii values for keyboard characters are not correct

Tags: python, ascii

I'm new to python and decided to build a keylogger (for learning purposes), the idea of this program is to take the Ascii value of any keystrokes and print out the corresponding character, I am not getting the correct Ascii values from my keystrokes. For example according to the Ascii table the character 'a' should have an Ascii value of 97 but my program spits it out with a value of 1 (which happens to be it's position in the alphabet).

My program:

```
import pythoncom
import pyHook


def key_event(event):
    if int(event.Ascii) != 0:
        keylog = chr(event.Ascii)
        if int(event.Ascii) == 13:
            keylog = '\n'
        print(keylog)
        return True

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = key_event
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

My IDE is pyCharm and it occasionally gives me this error regarding hm.HookKeyboard(): https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDDJU.jpg

And this notification regarding pythoncom.PumpMessages(): https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N9jS.jpg

I don't know if those errors have to do with my problem so I just thought I'd throw them in.

Comment: For debug purpose - before the line keylog = ...  please add: "print event.Ascii " to see which value do you get from the event.

Comment: I get the same output, this does not change the results

Comment: which values do you get from "print event.Ascii"?

Comment: When running print(event.Ascii) the values that print out are based on their position in the alphabet. For example, when enter the character 'a' I get the value 1, when entering the character 'z' I get the value 26 .... very weird.

Answer (score 0):

In a conda python 2.7 environment, I encountered a similar problem due to the fact that conda allows you to switch versions of python being used

The **problem** is that the C-language cache at the heart of python's interpreter and compiler is being shared between different versions of python. The pyHook library must make use of this cache when getting the key presses from the registry.

If running from  a command line switch to another version of python **not the same one** in which you intend to run the code.

Open the python interpreter (an example would be typing  python ) and in the interpreter input a variable with a value (example:  " `foo='bar'` "), then type  `exit()`

Now switch in the command line to the other version of python on which you want to run the code( for me in conda it is   "  `activate py27_32` "  I am switching from my default python 3.5 x64 64Bit to 2.7 x86 32Bit )

Finally when you run your code (example " `python myCode.py` " ), `event.Ascii` will return the propper key values as defined by Ascii

This process will need to be repeated for any re-runs of the code afterwards

It might be worth looking for a way to clear python's cache from inside python

A **quick hotfix** to get only characters defined in Ascii between 64 and 93 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]    is as follows

keyPressed = chr(int(event.Ascii) + 64)